# Python get value from different rows and columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:
the dataframe stores phone number, favorite food, and favorite toy for the kids (signed with different Ids). The data is separate in different rows and columns. Some rows may only has Id but nothing else. Input may looks like:

```
|Id|phone_number|food  |toy |
|--|------------|------|----|
|01|            |apple |    |
|01|9995552222  |banana|    |
|01|            |      |ball|
|01|9995552222  |orange|    |
|02|3332226666  |      |    |
|02|            |boba  |    |
|02|            |      |    |
```

What I want to get:
I want to combine the value in different rows together to make each row unique. The output may looks like:

```
|Id|phone_number|food  |toy |
|--|------------|------|----|
|01|9995552222  |apple |ball|
|01|9995552222  |banana|ball|
|01|9995552222  |orange|ball|
|02|3332226666  |boba  |    |
```

Thank you

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['01', '01', '01', '01', '02', '02', '02'], 
                'phone_number': ['', '9995552222', '', '9995552222', '3332226666', '', ''], 
                'food': ['apple', 'banana', '', 'orange', '', 'boba', ''], 
                'toy': ['', '', 'ball', '', '', '', '']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `groupby` `Id` column then fill the NaN column with `bfill` and `ffill`. At last drop the duplicates in 'phone_number', 'food', 'toy'.

```py
test = test.replace('', pd.NA)

out = (test.groupby('Id')
       .apply(lambda g: g.bfill().ffill())
       .drop_duplicates(['phone_number', 'food', 'toy']) # 'toy ' in your given dataframe
       .fillna('')
       )
```

```
print(df)

   Id phone_number    food   toy
0  01   9995552222   apple  ball
1  01   9995552222  banana  ball
2  01   9995552222  orange  ball
4  02   3332226666    boba
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as what I want!

Comment: Why do `apply`? `test.mask(test == '', np.nan).groupby('Id').ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates()` should be enough

Comment: @onyambu Only the first `ffill()` works on group, the second `bfill()` works on Series.